# Is this corporation electing to be an S corporation beginning with this tax year?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, limited-liability-company, s-corporation

I had a question about what to put for this answer in section G of Form 1120S.

I already filed Form 2553 the prior year to be accepted as having S-corp tax status for my LLC. Do I put "No" here since I already have this status or "Yes" since I am still wanting to be considered S-corp tax status for 2019?